# Python array conditions

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I wanna know how do I initialize a 2d array where the first row will have all even from 0-10, and 2nd row will have all odd from 11-20, so and so until in column 10 we will have 91-100 of all odd?
thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the [How](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to Ask page. StackOverflow is not a site where you strangers make your homework. It consists of volunteers that are happy to help - but you need to show what you have tried first.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ls = [];
 for i in range(10):
    temp = [];
    for j in range(i*10, (i+1)*10):
        if j%2==i%2:
            temp.append(j);
    ls.append(temp);
```

This should probably do it;